# androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity doesn't implement LifecycleOwner

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, androidx

I know looks like some stupid error, but I cannot find it.
In my project I have access to `LifecycleOwner` from my Fragments but not from Activity.

Here is my `build.gradle`

```
implementation project(':domain')
implementation project(':data')
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

// Koin for Android
implementation "org.koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$koin_version"

// Anko
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15-listeners:$anko_version"

//Architecture components
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```

Here is the Activity code:
[image]

And this is the source code of `AppCompatActivity`
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/126612680), this is a known issue if you use `core-ktx:1.1.0` and `appcompat:1.0.2`, mixing alpha versions with stable releases. Upgrade to `appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03` to fix the issue:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
```

Comment: You saved my day, killed 2 hours on that issue. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's your core library. Also general rule of thumb for production code, try to avoid using alpha. Update the following libraries and you should be fine.

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'
```

Comment: Those libraries have nothing to do with my problem. As @ianhanniballake stated it is related to `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'` and  `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1'` I should use both stable or both alpha versions.

Comment: ok if you got it fixed, I won't argue ;). I had the exact same issue, and simply changing the above libraries fixed it for me. I've encountered it twice now on two different projects and both times it was the above libraries. literally, just changing those versions and recompile Gradle did it for me. But the important thing is you got it fixed, so good on ya either way.