# How to properly "setMutableVisiblity"?

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin

I'm trying to create a function, `setMutableVisibility`. The thing is that I'm supposed to use another function but I got an error. I do not understand why. Furthermore one of my friend just did the same function on his computer but he didn't get the error...

```
@BindingAdapter("mutableVisibility")
fun setMutableVisibility(view: View, visibility: MutableLiveData<Int>?) {
    val parentActivity: AppCompatActivity? = view.getParentActivity()
    if(parentActivity != null && visibility != null) {
        visibility.observe(parentActivity, Observer{ value -> view.visibility = value?:View.VISIBLE})
    }
}
```

AS* is telling me that "parentActivity" is the wrong type, I think it's not the case.
But here the advice from AS :

> Type mismatch.
>   Required: LifecycleOwner
>   Found: AppCompatActivity?

Thank you for your answers.

*AS: Android Studio

Comment: From where are you calling this method?

Comment: My file : "BindingAdapters.kt

Comment: And what is version of AppCompat library dependency?

Comment: implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
I guess that's mean that's the wrong version x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue exist due to the fact that older support library does not integrate well with latest lifecycle components and there is some known issue / bug as mentioned by Ian in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303033/androidx-appcompat-app-appcompatactivity-doesnt-implement-lifecycleowner). You need to use latest version of AppCompat to fix this. Try:

> implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'

And make sure all other support libraries are also upgraded to compatible version (or same if it exists).